How to prove $\lim_{t \to 0}\max_{i}\{g_1(t),g_2(t)\}=\max_{i}\lim_{t \to 0}\{g_1(t),g_2(t)\}$
First, we have
$$
g_1(t) \leq \max \{g_1(t),g_2(t)\}\ \text{and} \
g_2(t) \leq \max \{g_1(t),g_2(t)\},\\
$$
pass limit, we have
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} g_1(t) \leq \max \{g_1(t),g_2(t)\}\ \text{and} \
\lim_{t \to 0} g_2(t) \leq \max \{g_1(t),g_2(t)\},\\
$$
then we obtain
$$
\max_{i}\lim_{t \to 0}\{g_1(t),g_2(t)\} \leq \lim_{t \to 0}\max_{i}\{g_1(t),g_2(t)\},
$$
if we can prove the reverse direction, then the conclution, but how to prove it, where $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$ are not necessary continuous.

The most general approach would be to show $\max(u,v)$ is a continuous function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R.$

Your notation doesn't quite make sense. What is the point of putting an "$i$" subscript on $\max$ if you have no "$i$" in the set you are taking the max of? And while there is a way for $\lim_{t\to 0}$ of a family of sets dependent on a parameter $t$ to make sense, it is likely something that hasn't been defined in your course, and for which you don't have all the nice theorems for handling. It would make far more sense to use $$\max {\lim_{t\to 0}g_1(t), \lim_{t\to 0}g_2(t)}$$ instead of $$\max_i \lim_{t\to 0}{g_1(t), g_2(t)}$$
